# Active Contribution Page not available in Insert CiviCRM Content in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

Atempting to add an active Contribution Page to a public Wordpress page but it is not available in the select field in Insert CiviCRM Content in Wordpress. Is this because I am using a separate database for CiviCRM? Using CiviCRM Worpdress Member Sync and it works properly.

Also, when I use the link for the Contribution page: https://domain.com/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=3 or the shortcode [civicrm component="contribution" id="3"]the page displays with the error: "You do not have permission to access this page." The Wordpress page has no content restriction on it.

And, finally a required Username field displays in the Contribution Page form, but no Password or Confirm Password fields. No option to add those on the Contribution Page settings. How do I add the required Password field so it is entered in the Wordpress User account?

Comment: What version of Civi are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Can you check [permissions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#access-control-permissions-in-wordpress) if the user has permission to make online donations?

If Civi is on 5.37 than password field is not available to set on form, the user will get a password reset link when the user is created.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, The permissions were correct, but I realized I had set the Profile fields added to the Contribution Page to User and User Admin instead of Expose Publicly. That problem solved and the password issue. First issue re Insert CiviCRM Content still unsolved.